# PSQL Batch Update Statement

Tags: sql-update, psql

I am trying to update a bunch of rows in a psql database, and would like to do it in one generated sql statement if possible. I am able to generate batch insert statements which look similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (v11, v12, v13), (v21, v22, v23), ...
```

However I am not sure how to do this with an update statement instead. I could do one SQL statement for each row I want to update but this seems unnecessary and slower than having just one statement

P.S. all rows have an id column so I can reference them through that

Answer (score 0):

[Near Bottom of Page](http://forums.devshed.com/postgresql-help-21/update-multiple-rows-615599.html)

I was able to find the answer at the above link. looks similar to

```
UPDATE my_table 
   SET x = case 
             when y = '1' then '1.1'
             when y = '2' then '1.2'
           end
WHERE y='1' OR y='2';
```